# Display specific data in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, popup

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
   var dmJSON = "clues.json";
   $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
      var idx=1;
      $.each(data.details, function(i, f) {
          var myid = 'mypop'+String(idx);
          idx++;
          var $popup="<popup id='"+myid+"' class='mystyles1'><tr>" + "<p>" + f.Myclue + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p>" + f.Description + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p>" + f.Updates + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p> " + f.Users + "</p></tr>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</popup>"
          $("#popup-container").append($popup)
      });
   });
});
```

**Html**

```
<div id="popup-box" class="popup-position">
    <div id="popup-wrapper">
        <p style="text-align: right;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box');">X</a></p>
         <div id="popup-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code i am trying to display my json data inside the popup window.

**JSON**

```
{
"details": [
  {
    "Myclue" : "First Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the first clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
  {
    "Myclue" : "Second Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the second clue",
    "Updates" : "Amazing",
    "Users" : "15"
  },
    {
    "Myclue" : "Third Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the third clue",
    "Updates" : "Spectacular",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Myclue" : "Fourth Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the fourth clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Myclue" : "Fifth Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the fifth clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Myclue" : "Sixth Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the sixth clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Myclue" : "Seventh Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the seventh clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Myclue" : "Eigth Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the eigth clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Myclue" : "Nintht Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the ninth clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Myclue" : "Tenth Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the ninth clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  }
]
}
```

But the problem is the entire data is displaying in a single popup. But what i want to achieve is, i want each set of data to be displayed in different popup.
For ex: This set of data should be displayed in one popup

```
{
    "Myclue" : "First Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the first clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
```

Then, this second set in another popup

```
{
    "Myclue" : "Second Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the second clue",
    "Updates" : "Amazing",
    "Users" : "15"
  },
```

.....and so on. I don't know what my error is since my popup appears when a table is clicked and my tables are created dynamically. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Could you show more HTML code with the (generated) tables and how you displaying the popup? Right now you're just generating all the popup content in the popup-container on the page load.

Answer (score 0):

Each set of data to been displayed in different popup. The only problem is each one have the same id i.e `mypop1`. you can use following to give unique id's

```
$(function() {
   var dmJSON = "clues.json";
   $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
      $.each(data.details, function(i, f) {
          var myid = 'mypop'+ (i+1);   // if you want to start id's from '1'
          var $popup="<popup id='"+myid+"' class='mystyles1'><tr>" + "<p>" + f.Myclue + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p>" + f.Description + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p>" + f.Updates + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p> " + f.Users + "</p></tr>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</popup>"
          $("#popup-container").append($popup)
      });
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/htjame9j/) by inspecting element you can see each `data` object is in different `<popup></popup>`